# Sequelize makes nested SELECT queries when applying WHERE to a joined table and “limit” in the options

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I’m trying to do a query on a model filtering by a property in an included model. This is how the sequelize options look.

```js
const result = await A.findAll({
    attributes: [
        "id",
        "field1",
        "field2",
    ],
    limit: 10,
    include: [
        {
            model: B,
            attributes: ["id"],
            where: {
                fieldC: { [Op.substring]: "value" }
            },
        }
    ]
});
```

And it executes this query in the database.

```sql
SELECT [a].*, [b].[Id] AS [b.id]
FROM (
    SELECT
           [a].[Id] AS [id],
           [a].[Field1] AS [field1],
           [a].[Field2] AS [field2]
    FROM [A] AS [a]
    WHERE (
        SELECT [Id]
        FROM [B] AS [b]
        WHERE (
            [b].[FieldC] LIKE N’%value%’ AND
            [b].[AId] = [a].[Id]
        )
        ORDER BY [b].[Id]
        OFFSET 0 ROWS
        FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
    ) IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY [a].[Id]
    OFFSET 0 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
) AS [a]
INNER JOIN [B] AS [b] ON [a].[id] = [b].[AId] AND [b].[FieldC] LIKE N’%value%’
ORDER BY [id];
```

I’m not sure why it does the nested queries if the below query would be enough. In fact, if I remove the "limit" field from the findAll options it executes a query like below (without the OFFSET and FETCH keywords)

```sql
SELECT
   [a].[Id] AS [id],
   [a].[Field1] AS [field1],
   [a].[Field2] AS [field2],
   [b].[Id] AS [b.id]
FROM [A] AS [a]
INNER JOIN [B] AS [b] ON [a].[Id] = [b].[AId] AND [b].[FieldC] LIKE N’%value%’
ORDER BY [a].[Id]
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Why would sequelize run the 1st query instead of a query like the 2nd one when the "limit" field is included in the options? Is there a way to force it to not do unnecessary nested queries?

Thanks

Comment: try adding `subQuery: false` to your `findAll`